# Arithmetic giving incorrect result

Tags: javascript

I need to evaluate the result of the following expression:

```
startCell = 50
size = 9
cnt = 1
var res = startCell + (size * cnt) + cnt
```

But if I alert `res`, I'm getting 591. What I should be getting is 60. I tried this:

```
var res = eval(startCell + (size * cnt) + cnt);
```

but it still gives me 591. Why is this happening?

Comment: remind me what this has to do with regex again...

Comment: cnt IS a string in this case.

Comment: @MayurBuragohain then what _is_ a string? `50+(9*1)+1` is definitely `59`, but `50+(9*'1')+'1' is `591`.

Comment: try this expression: `startCell + (size*cnt) + (+cnt)`. If the result is `60` then `cnt` is a string.

Comment: sry it was a string. apologies. i explicitly gave 1 and got 60.

Comment: @zaotaobao is it also this question you upvoted, and is it also because it was downvoted without explanation?

Comment: @JanDvorak i don't do anything, but i understand what you trying to tell me, i keep in mind for future down or up. ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. **Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8M7S/**

The cause of your problem is in the code we can't see. Something is turning `cnt` into a string, but `startCell` and `size` are still numbers. If they were all strings, you'd get `5091` instead of `591`: **http://jsfiddle.net/Q8M7S/1/**

It could be that `cnt` is being initialized to a string:

```
startCell = 50
size = 9
cnt = "1"
```

Or it could be initialized as a numeric value, but then transformed into a string by JavaScript's type coercion:

```
cnt = 1
cnt += ""
```

There are a lot of ways it could happen, and no one can know for sure without seeing the code. I suggest you look for every line that modifies `cnt` between the time you initialize it and the time you use it.

Also, be warned about `eval`. It's potentially dangerous when used incorrectly, and it's terrible for performance. You should avoid using `eval` when you can, at any skill level.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are adding integer and not concatenate some string

```
var res = parseInt(startCell)+(parseInt(size)*parseInt(cnt))+parseInt(cnt);
```

Comment: this is an overkill use. It would be better to find out which one of the variables is the actual string and make sure it is converted to a number before using in any formula.

Comment: multiplication always converts its arguments to number - not neccessary to put `parseInt` there. Also, you should pass two arguments to `parseInt` - string, and the base.